# Simple integer range for C++11 range-based for loops

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm really tired of having to type

```
for (int iSomething = rangeBegin; iSomething < rangeEnd; ++iSomething)
{
   ...
}
```

whenever I want to iterate over an integer range (most IDEs help with the typing, but still it looks so verbose, naming the integer 3 times!)

I wanted something like this:

```
for (int iSomething : LoopRange(rangeBegin, rangeEnd))
{
   ...
}
```

Or if `rangeBegin` is 0 (the majority of the cases) then a simple

```
for (int iSomething : LoopRange(rangeEnd))
{
   ...
}
```

My very simple implementation:

```
class LoopRangeIterator
{
public:
    LoopRangeIterator(int value_)
        : value(value_){}

    bool operator!=(LoopRangeIterator const& other) const
    {
        return value != other.value;
    }

    int const& operator*() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    LoopRangeIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

class LoopRange
{
public:
    LoopRange(int from_, int to_)
        : from(from_), to(to_){}

    LoopRange(int to_)
        : from(0), to(to_){}

    LoopRangeIterator begin() const
    {
        return LoopRangeIterator(from);
    }

    LoopRangeIterator end() const
    {
        return LoopRangeIterator(to);
    }

private:
    int const from;
    int const to;
};
```

I named it `LoopRange` to make it clear that it's for loops and it isn't some general integer range class that you would use for intersecting or building union etc.

Of course this class could be generalized in many ways, but I think if you need more complex functionality (e.g. custom step sizes, double values), then you are doing something special and you are better off writing the explicit for loop.

What do you think about it?
If I use such a thing throughout my project, would it confuse and disturb/distract people too much compared to just using the classic and verbose `for(...; ...; ...)` style?

Comment: Take a look at my implementation at [klmr/cpp11-range](https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range). Needless to say, I think my implementation has a few good ideas which set it apart from other implementations (the README explains these).

Comment: You shouldn't fear to add a `step` argument. It is common enough that Python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) built-in functions provides it.

Comment: @Morwenn Python, unlike C++, has named arguments. I feel that without name it would be un-intuitive enough to warrant this special treatment. Furthermore, the `step` argument creates a separate type which makes optimisation somewhat easier for the compiler (it can use `++` instead of `+= var` for the simple case).

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are probably right. I've never seen anybody explicitely name this argument though (some people probably do, but it seems that the vast majority doesn't).

Comment: You should take in account the case where client code supplies a `from` value that is bigger than `to`.

Comment: @Erevis Good point. That should either result in an empty range or an exception. Although I think the STL algorithms don't try to prevent such things at all (i.e. providing the iterators in the wrong order to something like `std::find`).

Comment: Just a note: [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) also takes a step parameter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why write it yourself if you can use [**Boost.Range**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)'s [`irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html). You can even adapt this to set the starting index to `0` and get `std::iota` type behavior (called `iota_n` here).

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<class Integer>
decltype(auto) iota_n(Integer last)
{
    return boost::irange(0, last);    
}

template<class Integer, class StepSize>
decltype(auto) iota_n(Integer last, StepSize step_size)
{
    return boost::irange(0, last, step_size);    
}

int main()
{
    for (auto x : iota_n(5)) // 01234
        std::cout << x;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/524df49d8e711f96), using Clang 3.4 return-type-deduction in C++1y mode (also supported by gcc 4.9, and other compilers soon (use trailing `-> decltype(/*statement inside function*/)` return types for C++11 compilers)

Comment: Yes, I looked into it and chose this. But I also wrote a wrapper function that takes a single parameter (to) and sets the beginning to zero, as in python.

Comment: @isarandi yes, that would a useful wrapper (`std::iota` like behavior)

Comment: @isarandi updated with a thin wrapper that counts from 0.

Comment: @isandri: This is incorrect.  Boost::irange(0,3,2) does give you 0,2. Note also that range(0,2) is the same as range(0,2,1) and gives 0,1.

Comment: Why? Because you: 1. Must install Boost and 2. Must include super-long-and-slow-to-compiler Boost headers.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. Boost comes installed on most dev systems, and if not, it's not a big burden. 2. Apart from say heavy metaprogramming libraries (Fusion, MPL, Spirit), most of Boost is not heavier on the compiler than the Standard Library, which leads to 3. much of Boost has historically been treated as "pre-STL", with heavy emphasis on correctness and speed (runtime).

Comment: @TemplateRex Nevertheless this is not always an option. Sure this is often a possible solution but now always.

Comment: I needed `boost::irange(static_cast<Integer>(0), last)` for it to work with `size_t` (`unsigned long`).

Answer (score 22):

You can make the class template with trivial changes (add `template<typename T>` and change `int` by `T` in your classes), then make a construction function that deduces integer types:

```
template<typename T>
LoopRange<T> range(T from, T to)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                  "range only accepts integral values");

    return { from, to };
}
```

That will even allow you to explicitly tell what kind of integer you want to loop with if needed:

```
for (auto i: range<unsigned>(0, 5))
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

If you need to generate indices to iterate through a `std::vector`, this can be useful since `std::vector<T>::size_type` is probably bigger than `int`. While the `static_assert` avoids some potential problems with floating point values, it also inhibits the use of integer-like classes (for example, a hypothetical `BigNum` class).

---

You can simplify some of your functions thanks to [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). For example, used in a `return` statement, it sallows you not to explicitly repeat the return type (unless the return type's constructor is `explicit`):

```
LoopRangeIterator begin() const
{
    return { from };
}

LoopRangeIterator end() const
{
    return { to };
}
```

---

On a side note, such a `range` utility would also be interesting if it worked with floating point numbers, and maybe decimal numbers in the future (akin to Python's [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)). However, you would have to special-case the class for those types if you want to avoid problems: if you repeatedly add the same floating point (say `0.01`), you will accumulate rounding errors. Computing every value from the base value with a multiplication could be away to circumvent such a problem.

Comment: The problem with the template solution is that floating point numbers would need more care. If you repeatedly add an increment to a floating point number it may never hit the expected "end" value. So I'd need some tricks (e.g. keeping track of the number of remaining iterations). It would be too much complication for a rare use case. I could probably restrict template instantiation to integral types with some template magic but why overcomplicate things?

Comment: @qorilla A little `static_assert` should do the trick :)

Comment: While `return { from };` is shorter to type, I don't think it is better than `return LoopRangeIterator(from);` from a readability and maintainability point of view.

Comment: @RSahu There have been [long debates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4094.html) about that recently, even in the standard committee itself, so it's still debatabe. My point of view is that when you return from a one-liner, there is no way you could mean anything else and writing the return type a second time doesn't help much.

Answer (score 11):

If you have `operator!=`, you should also have `operator==` for symmetry:

```
bool operator==(LoopRangeIterator const& other) const
{
    return value == other.value;
}
```

In addition, it's more common to overload `operator!=` in terms of `==`:

```
bool operator!=(LoopRangeIterator const& other) const
{
    return !(value == other.value);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense in general. Here I concentrated on the functionality needed in the for loop as I intend this class to be used nowhere else.

Comment: @qorilla: That's fine.  I would still follow this rule, at least with operator-overloading.  It may also seem a bit tacky when you have one overload but not the other.

Answer (score 6):

I liked MORTAL's code so much I improved it.
1st, I needed it to have a template type rather than int.
2nd, I needed it to have start/stop/step with operator++ jumping by step.
The resulting code (below) enables nesting loops such as:

```
// range code improved from MORTAL
template <typename T,T iBegin,T iEnd,T iStep=1>
class range {
    public:
        struct iterator {
            T value;
            iterator    (T v) : value(v) {}
            operator T  () const         { return value; }
            operator T& ()               { return value; }
            T operator* () const         { return value; }
            iterator& operator++ ()      { value += iStep; return *this; }
        };
        iterator begin() { return iBegin; }
        iterator end() { return iEnd; }
};

// Sample code using the improved code
for (auto jj: range<size_t,0,256,16>()) {
    for (auto ii: range<size_t,0,16>()) {
        // just show the result as a 16x16 table
        cout << hex << setw(3) << (jj+ii);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I hope this is useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a nested iterator class so you don't need to have two exposed template classes. Maybe this is better - I think it's tidier

```
template <class T> class range {
private:
    class iter {
    private:
        T at;
    public:
        iter(T at) : at(at) {}
        bool operator!=(iter const& other) const { return at != other.at; }
        T const& operator*() const { return at; }
        iter& operator++() { ++at; return *this; }
    };

    T begin_val;
    T end_val;
public:
    range(T begin_val, T end_val) :
        begin_val(begin_val), end_val(end_val) { }
    iter begin() { return iter(begin_val); }
    iter end() { return iter(end_val); }
};
```

used as:

```
for (auto i: range<unsigned>(0, 5))
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Preprocessor Macros! All of the loops below will produce the same result. Unfortunately, macros can't be defined more than once, so you have to give them different names.

```
#include <iostream>

#define irange(i,a,b) int i = (a); i < (b); ++i // if you want to use ints all the time
#define range(i,a,b) i = (a); i < (b); ++i      // if you ever want to use something other than an int
#define zrange(i,b) i = 0; i < (b); ++i       // if you want to start at zero
#define izrange(i,b) int i = 0; i < (b); ++i  // if you want to start at zero and use ints

int main ( )
{
    for ( int num = 0; num < 10; ++num ) std::cout << num << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( irange ( num, 0, 10 ) ) std::cout << num << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( int range ( num, 0, 10 ) ) std::cout << num << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( int zrange ( num, 10 ) ) std::cout << num << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( izrange ( num, 10 ) ) std::cout << num << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You could also write more macros to do things like increment by something other than 1.

Comment: Well, this is not as clean as a modern C++ solution. For the reasons you mentioned and for all the other reasons we try to avoid macros :/

Comment: but I did it in one line. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, in real code, we value the usage and quality of the implementation more than its character count :p

Comment: This kind of use of macros is discouraged. It makes static analysis harder.

Comment: Ew... Macros...

Comment: Nicely done. Because when the macro solution is vastly simpler and more readable (wth is an "iota"?) than the "modern c++" solution, it starkly reminds us there is work left to do. See also the journey to get to "format" in order to, after decades, get back some of the usability of bad ol' printf. The preprocessor that we "someday" won't need has always been an important driver of C++ language progress.